# ip address change = start a certian app

Tags: applescript

im using a mac, and with the script editor or automator, i would like to run an app automatically when i connect to specific ip addresses i have been trying the script editor with this:

```
if IP address is changed to "192.168.2.102" or "192.168.2.103" 

tell application "app" activate end tell
```

but it is still needing more from me...
i may not be even close but i have no experience with this at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on idle` to make your script running on background. Take the example below:

```
global ipValue

on idle
    set newIpValue to do shell script "curl -s http://checkip.dyndns.org | sed 's/[a-zA-Z/<> :]//g'" as string

    if not (newIpValue = ipValue) then
        -- perform your action
    end if

    return 10 -- time in seconds to perform checking
end idle
```

Also, you have to mark **stay open** on AppleScript's save dialog when saving your script as an application.

I'm not sure which IP you want, but this example get's your web IP from http://checkip.dyndns.org.

Comment: hey thanks so much for answering, i was hoping to get it to activate the app for both ip addresses, so would i just place the ip addresses in at "(newIpValue = ipValue)" and specify the app to run?

Comment: Use: `if newIpValue = "192.168.2.102" or newIpValue = "192.168.2.103" then`. But the newIpValue is setting the IP from internet. I guess you're trying to check the local ip.